# "in" statement in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does Javascript or jQuery have sometime like the "in" statement in Python?

"a" in "dea" -> True

Googling for the word *in* is hopeless :(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It does have an [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Operators/Special_Operators#in) but is restricted to object keys only:

```
var object = {
    a: "foo",
    b: "bar"
};

// print ab
for (var key in object) {
    print(key);
}
```

And you may also use it for checks like this one:

```
if ("a" in object) {
    print("Object has a property named a");
}
```

For string checking though you need to use the [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) method:

```
if ("abc".indexOf("a") > -1) {
    print("Exists");
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's the only answer that actually answers the question..?

Comment: The question is about finding a string within a string.

Comment: Aha. I don't know Python, so I read the question to be about the `in` statement in javascript. Makes sense now.

Comment: @Matt Grande, that doesn't mean we shouldn't tell him about the in operator.

Answer (score 6):

you would need to use indexOf

e.g

`"dea".indexOf("a");` will return 2

If its not in the item then it will return -1

I think thats what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need regular expressions!

```
if ("dea".match(/a/))
{ 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That's using a sledgehammer to put up a picture hook. Use indexOf.

Comment: "dea".test(/a) is more efficient in that context as it just returns true or false directly, eliminating the overhead of constructing a match object and then working out if it's null or not to derive true or false before throwing it away.

Comment: Also, what @DavidDorward said ;-)

Comment: Good to know about the test method, thanks.  Also, is indexOf noticeably faster than RegEx in this case?  I find matching true/false easier to read than checking if it's greater than -1.

Answer (score 1):

How about [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

With the `indexOf` function, you can extend the String like such:

```
String.prototype.in = function (exp) {
    return exp.indexOf(this) >= 0;
}

if ("ab".in("abcde")) { //true

}
```

Comment: And people accused ME of using a sledgehammer to put up a picture hook... :P

Comment: haha well I still used indexOf, not regExp ;P ...i just made it easier to use

Comment: I'd rather make a String.prototype.contains(substring) method. Anyway, nice idea.

Comment: I used "in" to conform to the OP's original request