# Modernizr IE skips "unload"

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Reading
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js#L198

What does this mean:

```
// When using `setAttribute`, IE skips "unload", WebKit skips "unload" and "resize", whereas `in` "catches" those
var isSupported = eventName in element;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119336/in-statement-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: I think the question is about that comment line, not so much about the `in` expression, but I could be wrong.

Comment: yes it is about the comment line and if someone can elaborate on it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what the comment means, I think it has to do with the code in the `if` statement after that. If the simple `in` test fails, then the code tries calling `setAttribute()` to create a dummy event handler.  Apparently, some browsers ignore such attempts according to that comment. Thus the `in` test is made first.

That is, I'm thinking that it means that this code at line 208:

```
        isSupported = is(element[eventName], 'function');
```

will return a "false negative" for some events.

Comment: thanks. looks like its there to avoid false negative like you said